# Is there any way to continuously update readme file of one repo to another repo?

Tags: git

Say I have a repo A and B, which has readme.md file. If I push/merge anything to A with changes in readme.md than it should get replicated in B also.

I would need this as I wanted to keep documentation files in separate project to maintain the ambience of UI.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of version control that you get to update things and see the changes in other repos? I don't understand your question at all...

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "maintain the ambience of UI?" I feel this falls under "can I use Git as a release manager?" You can hack something together, but Git is not a release manager. What you can do is put the docs into their own repo and [add the doc repo to the code repo as a submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: I think sub-module should work. I will give a try on it